# Is there an android app that adds short vowels to Persian texts?

Tags: vowels, persian

I found an app for [Arabic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Tashkeel).

But is there an app or maybe a website for Persian too?

Comment: Maybe this should be migrated to a language learning site, as it doesn't seem to be a linguistics topic strictly speaking?

Comment: Maybe, I'm new to this site.

Comment: If you know Python (programming language) and how to read IPA, you can use [this phonemizer tool](https://github.com/bootphon/phonemizer) to convert the Perso-Arabic text to IPA (which will have short vowels as well), then map the IPA back to Perso-Arabic using a Python script.